# OpenCL kernel parameter without pointer

Tags: parameters, kernel, opencl

suppose I have this kernel:

```
__kernel void myKernel(
    __global uint* output, 
             uint count)
```

In which memory region does the parameter count reside? Can I put __constant or __private in front of it? In order to have it in constant memory or in a register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCL spec says that all function arguments (which would include kernel arguments) are stored in `private` address space:

> Variables inside a kernel function not declared with an address space qualifier, all variables inside non-kernel functions, and **all function arguments** are in the **__private or private address space**.

Comment: Even though it is defined like that in the OpenCL spec, and makes complete sense since it would stay in a constant register. I found by experience that an argument declared inside the kernel can help with memory bottle necked kernels(even though just a little). So, this means these variables as arguments are in `__constant` memory space and they do use bandwidth to retrieve them, at least for the first time. Additionally they forbid the compiler to optimize out the inner code.